# Does Docker Cloud bring your own nodes need to all have the same OS?

Tags: docker-cloud

Currently, all our nodes are on Ubuntu, but I'm considering switching to CentOS. But I want to stagger the switch over.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.
See [Introducing Docker Cloud](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/intro_cloud/#what-is-a-node)

> You can also provide your own node or nodes. This means you can use any **Linux host** connected to the Internet as a Docker Cloud node as long as you can install a Cloud agent. The agent registers itself with your Docker account, and allows you to use Docker Cloud to deploy containerized applications.